# Problems with table when using multicolumn and nested tabular

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

I have two problems with a table as highlighted in red in the figure below.

1. First, on the left, the multirow cell containing the text "Number" is not aligned at the center of the cell. I believe this happens because I have used a tabular inside the cell containing the "Very long category name distributed on two rows"; I did this because I need this text to be on two rows and I do not know another way to do that.
2. The cell containing "Category" is obtained using multirow but as you can see on the right, there is no vertical bar. I have no idea why this happens.

Anyone knows how I can fix this? Here is my code with a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} 
 \hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{Number} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Category} \\ \cline{2-5}  
 & \begin{tabular}{c} Very long category name \\ distributed on two rows \end{tabular}  & cat.\ A & cat.\ B & \begin{tabular}{c} Another very long name \\ on two rows \end{tabular}\\
 \hline
 abc & def & ghi & jkl & mno\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: the package `multicol` is for having _text_ in multiple columns, it has nothing to do with tables. The macro `\multicolumn` is defined in the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: Thanks @campa for your suggestion, I removed `multicol` from my code!

Comment: Since multicolumn overrides stuff you'll have to add the vertical line manually thus use `{c|} ` not `{c} `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also draw that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` with two advantages:

- Instead of `\multirow`, you have a command `\Block`; with that command (which may be used to merge cells vertically but also horizontally), you have to specify the number of *rows* (and the number of columns) whereas, with `\multirow`, you have to specify the number of physical lines (which requires sometimes tuning as in your case).
- In `{NiceTabular}`, you have a key `hvlines` which draws all the rules, excepted in the blocks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[hvlines]
    \Block{2-1}{Number} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Category} \\ 
    & \begin{tabular}{c} Very long category name \\ distributed on two rows \end{tabular}  
    & cat.\ A & cat.\ B & \begin{tabular}{c} Another very long name \\ on two rows \end{tabular}\\
    abc & def & ghi & jkl & mno\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However, you need several compilations since `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[t]
        \begin{center}
            
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} 
                \hline
                \multirow{3.5}{*}{Number} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Category} \\ \cline{2-5}  
                & \begin{tabular}{c} Very long category name \\ distributed on two rows \end{tabular}  & cat.\ A & cat.\ B & \begin{tabular}{c} Another very long name \\ on two rows \end{tabular}\\
                \hline
                abc & def & ghi & jkl & mno\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain why the `3.5` value in the `multirow`? It does not seem to be exactly centered if I zoom in

Comment: `\multirow{3}{*}{Number}` should vertically center the word "Name"  and thus result in the  desired output.

Comment: it was purely to show the multirow command can take decimals for fine tuning -- you can experiment with the appropriate number -- i use 3.5 since with 3 it was aligning with the horizontal rule under Category